# How is "I am to be" or "we are to be" expressed in French?

Tags: traduction

Consider this statement in English: From what I heard, when we reach Paris, we are to be wined and dined like kings and queens! In everyday translators, "we are to be" comes out as "nous devons être". But, the intention in English with "we are to be" is not to express "we must be", but to add pomp and circumstance to "we will be".

So my question is: In everyday French, is "nous devons être" actually used in this way, or is "nous sommes être" correct?

If it is neither, then what should it be?

Thinking of the intent in English terms, "nous sommes être" seems correct, whereas "nous devons être" seems to imply compulsion or insistence.

Comment: For me in English: we are to be wined and dined necessarily implies something has been arranged or set up or is in the works. Just as in:  We are to be met at the airport by a car. We are to be seen by a doctor. We are to be hosted by John. We're to be picked up at 5 o'clock. The prisoner was to be taken to jail.

Comment: I have upvoted all three answers so far as they have been useful to me. There seems to be some confusion about the question and I will edit it after I've spent some more time digesting all three answers and all the comments, then I'll delete this comment. Bear with me, thank you all, for all your input.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid ***nous***, which has essentially disappeared as subject in spoken French, and is formal when written and translate the idiom "**to be wined and dined** (like kings and queens)" by ***être reçu comme des rois***. That might also be ***accueillis en grande pompe*** if you want to insist on the fanfare.

***Devoir*** is ambiguous, it doesn't necessarily mean an obligation, just that it is anticipated so the following sentence is possible, although the context is needed to tell what meaning is expected:

> On **doit** être reçus comme des rois

If you are confident it will be the case, you can just say this:

> On **va** être reçus comme des rois
> On **va** être accueillis en grande pompe

If you want it to happen:

> Si on **veut** être reçus comme des rois, il faut qu'on prévienne de notre arrivée.

*Être* can't be conjugated with itself so *<s>nous sommes être</s>* is impossible. ***Nous allons être*** is fine, as well as ***on va être*** already suggested.

Comment: Downvoted by a ***nous*** fanboy or for something else?

Comment: Ça va retarder les 200k ! J'annule le -1

Comment: @Personne Merci ! Je me demande encore en me relisant ce qui a bien pu motiver ce vote négatif...

Comment: Cela m'est arrivé aussi … à la retraite des réponses, ma cagnotte suit le niveau de vie, surtout quand les “négationnistes fantômes” quittent l'arène :-) ——— STOP … sinon on se retrouve sur Causette. ;-(

Comment: That's right devoir **here** is completely ambiguous. are to be [verb[ can even mean "should be [past participle] in English, sometimes. However, "are/is to be + past participle" verb is an idiomatic usage which implies someone has arranged something: We are to be seen by a doctor. means: On a pris rendez-vous avec un médecin pour nous. There is always someone or something in the background with this usage.

Answer (score 2):

"Nous devons être" is the most basic rendering and even in those cases when it is acceptable it is not likely to express too faithfully the particular nuance found in "we are to". "Nous sommes être" is incorrect.

This form does not have  a unique translation. For this instance itself there are several possibilities, each depending on the particular context.

- From what I heard, when we reach Paris, **we are to** be wined and dined like kings and
  queens!

  - D'après ce qui a été dit, lorsque nous serons à Paris **on peut compter sur**  des  libations et des repas dignes de rois et reines.
  - D'après ce qui a été dit, lorsque nous serons à Paris **il faut s'attendre à**  des  libations et des repas dignes de rois et reines.
  - D'après ce qui a été dit, **il est prévu pour nous** à notre arrivée à Paris  des  libations et des repas dignes de rois et reines. (*a likely candidate in the way of rendering the idea of pomp and circumstance*)

*A few other instances*

> - If **we are to** be believed we'd better suppress this type of behaviour.
> - Si **nous voulons être** crus nous avons intérêt à réprimer cette sorte de comportement. (*"si nous devons être" does seem to express the idea well.*)

> - This car **is not to** be driven before its breaks have been repaired.
> - Il **ne faut pas** conduire cette voiture tant que ses freins n'ont pas été réparés. (*"personne ne doit" is a real possibility.*)

> - We **are to** get a small cut on this deal.
> - **Il est prévu que** nous obtenions un petit pourcentage sur cette affaire. (*"nous devons" is possible in this context but weak.*)

> - "He didn't even propose a little help, but I'll have my revenge, ***we are to* meet again**, I can feel it." said she.
> - « Il ne m'a même pas fait la moindre offre d'aide, mais je me vengerai, **nous nous retrouverons**, je le sens. » dit-elle. (*"devoir" won't do in the present case.*)

Comment: _On peut compter sur_ and similar seem to me to stress the wrong point of view, so to speak. _We are to be_ here indicates that someone else has made plans and _they_, not we, are the ones expecting and counting on things. My instinct would be something more along the lines of “lorsque nous serons à Paris, des libations et des repas dignes de rois et reines nous attendront (attendent?)” or something along those lines, but I’m not a native speaker, so that may not be idiomatic. (Incidentally, I’d naturally say “d’après ce qu’on m’a dit, quand on arrive à Paris…” – is that natural?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "on peut compter sur": "we might not be so interested, but it's a sure thing" _or_  (enthusiastically) "it's a sure thing, so, in the mean time let's be sober". (I do not see anything that could be wrong; wrong on what ground?)// The use of "attendre", imo, precludes that of "lorsque": while they are on their way towards the city, the cocktail parties, meals and so on are already "waiting" for them, awaiting them (as you say, people have plans). As formulated, the sentence does not make  precise whether the duration of these festivities is limited  (1/3)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  to a brief moment after the arrival or  if it will extend over a longer span; in this latter case it seems that "attendre" is not so appropriate. // "d’après ce qu’on m’a dit, quand on arrive à Paris…" : that is quite natural and closer to the original, but presupposes  (as, anyway, also does "D'après ce qui a été dit") that the people talking thus are not too well informed about what to expect, and are perhaps taking part in an organized tour; if that sort of entertainment is oftentimes rather expensive, it is not quite what most people associate with pump;  (2/3)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet   so the initial sentence does not fit the case of pump too well. (3/3)

Comment: The bit about point of view was that in English, ‘we are to be wined and dined’ – despite having ‘we’ as its subject – sets ‘us’ up as rather passive. ‘On peut compter sur’ (assuming that _on_ = _nous_ here) would be more akin to ‘we may count on being wined and dined’ in that it sets ‘us’ up as active participants with active expectations. It’s a minute difference, but at least in English, it is there. // You’re right about the time – I read it as being a single meal, but it could be a general thing as well. _On nous donnera des libations…_, perhaps (though that’s quite prosaic)?

Comment: (Also, the thing you use to fill up your car or splash water from a hose is a pump, but – confusingly, in relation to the French spelling – the bombastic bravado is _pomp_ and circumstance in English.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I fail to see the bombast and bravado in manifestations referred to as pomp and circumstance. My small dictionary sees in that nothing else than "impressive ceremony"; important  occasions  and personages surely deserve ceremonies out of the ordinary.

Comment: Bombastic bravado was just my description. Although ‘impressive ceremony’ is a possible meaning of _pomp_, it is old-fashioned. The more common meaning, especially of the phrase _pomp and circumstance_, is “ostentatious and vain display, especially of dignity or importance” – the ostentatious part being quite central to the meaning, and what makes it frequently bombastic. But the meaning was not my point – I was just pointing out that it’s spelt _pomp_, not _pump_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I've got it, thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the error where I could, that is in my answer (I never learned that word well). But, more important is this point of view, which in all evidence is not just your personal point of view. It is very surprising.

Comment: The given translations sound much more formal than the English does. To add a slightly more casual phrasing: "On me dit que lorsque nous arrivons à Paris, nous serons fêtés comme des rois!"

Comment: @KitKatKit Should be *arriverons* and it's still formal.

Comment: I will edit my question, because pomp and circumstance is not the only use of this phrase. "I gather that when we arrive in London, we are to be collected by an agent."  There's a mark of importance in that without the pomp. Relying on what "we are to be expecting" to express the emphasis doesn't work in this case. That is, obvious formality, but without the pomp.

Comment: @GeoffPointer As you could  mind small irregularities in your writing, I thought I'd tell you  that in your profile post is found an occurrence of "both both".

Comment: ***Nous devons être*** is a translation error here.

Comment: @Lambie "We are to be introduced to the delegate shortly.": Wouldn't the sentence "Nous devons être présentés au délégué très bientôt." be a translation?

Comment: No, it would not. It means: An introduction to the delegate has been arranged.

Comment: @Lambie That is  not so; your interpretation is just one possibility: ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/be_2) : ​be to do something used to say what must or should be done —  ex: 
I am to call them once I reach the airport.

Comment: "I am to call them" is not the same usage: here there is **a past participle**. is/are to be [past participle]. Your statement to Geoff above re his writing is the pot calling the kettle black.

Answer (score 0):

are to be [past participle verb], is to be etc.
This is not a simple idiom. It's complicated.

and here, it means:

2 - **used for saying what has been arranged**
The ceremony is to take place on the U.S.S. Missouri.

The dictionary says American English but this usage of "is to be/are to be [past participle] is also British English.

The Collins Dictionary says this can be: *il a été décider de or il a été convenu que*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/arrange)

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-to-do-something)

So: we are to be wined and dined like kings and queens!

can be translated in several ways:

- Il a été décidé que nous serons [ou: nous allons être] fêtés commes des rois et des reines.
- Il a été convenu que nous etc.

To see this more easily, think of: We are to be met at the airport by a car.
That does mean: A car has been arranged to meet us at the airport.

[Please note the references for the French translation and the English meaning.]

Comment: But "it has been arranged" probably isn't the meaning of "we are to be" the OP wanted. As the OP says, it just means "we will be" with "extra pomp and circumstance."  Dictionaries don't always give all possible meanings of every phrase. (*il a été convenu ...* would be a fine trnaslation of *we are to be met at the airport ...*)

Comment: @PeterShor If there is pomp and circumstance, *someone has organized it or arranged it*. Il a été convenu is in the Collins. I did say it can be translated **several ways**. There is nothing written in stone except that Nous devons être is not accurate.